# recycler view and listview not scrolling in nested fragment that has viewpager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

After upgrading my project to latest android build tools 23.0.2 and compilesdk 23 my listviews contained in fragments added to the MainActivity are nolonger scrolling. I have searched for 3 days trying different solutions in vain. Please help.

**XML for the fragment with viewpager**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pagerz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
     />
```

**Fragment with listView that doesnt scroll**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/accounts_list_fragment_linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"


        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
            android:text="@string/addAccount1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/account_type_icon_description"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_new_acc" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_item_vert_margin"
            android:text="@string/addAccount2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/totalAmountView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_totalView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"

            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<net.i2p.android.ext.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/fam_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/accent"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/accent_light"
    fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">

    <net.i2p.android.ext.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_newAccount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent_light"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_title="New Account"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_new_trn"/>

    <net.i2p.android.ext.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_newTransaction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent_light"
        fab:fab_size="mini"
        fab:fab_title="New Transaction"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_new_ac"/>


</net.i2p.android.ext.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

Comment: Try setting the ListView's height to wrap_content